# enable debug point in eclipse for groovy file with extension .idsl

Tags: eclipse, groovy, dsl

I have a groovy dsl file with extension .idsl but in eclipse unable to set debug point in that file.

i am getting error like below

Toggle Line Breakpoint".
Compilation unit name must end with .java, or one of the registered Java-like extensions

[image]

Comment: Please don't post only images of code or error messages. They have to be in text format. Please edit the question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47992457/edit) link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "idsl" as a Groovy content type.  You can do this in Eclipse under Window > Preferences > General > Content Types.  In the content types tree, expand Text > Java Source File > Groovy Source File.  Select "Groovy Source File" and click Add Child... button.  Give new content type a name and click OK.  Then select it and click Add... button in lower "File associations" pane and type "*.idsl" in the dialog and click OK.